# nginx location 404 not found for reactjs

Tags: reactjs, nginx, deployment

Works only main URL example.com if I type example.com/somepage I observe 404 error in the browser.

My nginx configuration:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root  /var/www/html/dist;

        index index.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
}
```

Actually it is all that I have, I'm pretty new in Ubuntu

Comment: I think you have to add the matching route on where should nginx route when you give ..../somepage

Comment: I can't add all pages

Comment: Ofcourse not all pages. It will be managed via your front-end. But in Nginx you will just give a base path and then a wildcard character. I will find an example and update it here shortly.

Comment: Check your configuration using `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) and make sure that the `server` block in your question is the only `server` block. Because the configuration you have in your question cannot generate a 404 response.

Comment: @RichardSmith yes you right. I have some issues here. I have other config file # configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/galyan.conf. But this config is empty

Comment: @RichardSmith I've deleted this config. created a new one after I call nginx -T I can't see any config. the site doesn't work at all now.

Comment: If you cannot see your configuration file in `nginx -T` then Nginx is not reading it. The top level configuration file is something like `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and in that file are `include` statements that pull in other files. Presumably the directory or filename or permissions of your new configuration file is preventing Nginx from reading it.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks soo much!